# creating vertex group for multiple objects

Tags: objects, vertices, vertex-groups, select

I want to create vertex group of multiple objects , but it appears that you can only select one object at a time. Is there a way to assign multiple objects for vertex group?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Since *Vertex groups* are a property of *mesh*, not *object*, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: thanks. I think i've to find different approach for this problem